# python get screen width height cron

Tags: python

What would we appropriate tool to get user system screen resolaution, like width and height in pixels.

Have tried:

- GTK
- os.popen("xrandr -q -d :0").readlines()[0]

Both have issues with

```
 display ":0"
```

Comment: Are you running a cron job? Is so, there simply is no screen to look at. crom does not connect to the X display

Comment: any other pyhon alternative

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

or

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
print "width =", GetSystemMetrics (0)
print "height =",GetSystemMetrics (1)
```

These are both for windows

If you want to use wxPython use (cross platform):

```
import wx

wx.App(False) # The wx.App object must be created first!    
print wx.GetDisplaySize()
```

with linux you can use something like

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.Popen('xrandr | grep "\*" | cut -d" " -f4',shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print output
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: @user2120021 I must admit that I have never used cron but I assumed that one of these would work, is it Unix-Based?